# How to Set Up Bounds for a Double Integral on a Polar Region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I found the volume of the solid by doing a double integration, however, it was deemed wrong and I am unsure as to why.

The problem statement is to find the volume that lies under the double cone $ z^2=4x^2 + 4y^2 $ inside the cylinder $ x^2 + y^2 = x $ and above the plane $ z=0 $.

To setup my region, $R$, I achieved $$R = \Big\{ (r,\theta) \mid 0\le r \le cos(\theta), 0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2} \Big\},$$

To set up my integral, I found $z=2r$ by changing $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = rsin(\theta)$ and simplifying which achieved: $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{cos(\theta)} (2r)rdrd\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{cos(\theta)} 2r^2drd\theta $$

From here, I simplified the first integral which resulted in $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2cos^3(\theta)}{3}d\theta = \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-sin^2(\theta))cos\theta d\theta$$

I then used u-sub with $u=sin\theta$, and I achieved my final answer to be $\frac{4}{9}$.

The only mistake I feel like I may have made is the bounds of the radius, $\theta$ is definitely in range $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ because it is above the $z$-plane so it is only the top half of the cone.

Comment: I can't think of any other bounds for the radius, if $x^2 + y^2 = x$ then, the radius must be $x$, so the bounds of the radius is from $0$ to $cos\theta$. Correct?

Comment: "above the $z$-plane" does not necessarily imply $\theta\in\left[0,\dfrac\pi2\right]$, that information is relevant for choosing $z^2=4r^2\implies z=+2r$. With this range, you integrate only over [half of the cylinder](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polar+plot+cos%28theta%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2).

Comment: @user170231 Oh, I see what you are saying. Essentially, I integrated only the first quadrant of the surface? So then $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Too much; $r=\cos\theta$ is a circle tangent to the $y$-axis and does not belong to the second and third quadrants.

Comment: @user170231 I see, if it doesn't belong in the second quadrant then $\theta$ can't be in $[0,pi]$ - would I integrate with $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and then integrate $\theta \in [\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi]$ and then add those two integrals together to get the integration over the first and fourth quadrants? Edit: I just did that, and achieved $\frac{8}{9}$ which was the right answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In this case any interval of length $\pi$ would work because that's as much as is needed for $r=\cos\theta$ to complete a single loop; I would have vied for $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ myself.